# winrar not closing correctly?

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, winrar

I have this script that runs by a windows task scheduler once a week:

for /f "delims==" %%D in ('DIR D:\scripts /A /B /S') do ( "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.EXE" a -agyyyy-MM-dd -r "c:\backup\scripts.rar" "%%D" )

by a bat file.  My question is after this bat file runs and completes, I look in my windows task manager i still have around 10 winrar.exe running, does it mean that my script/bat is not closing winrar correctly?  am i missing something at the end of the script?

Answer (score 1):

Using the command-line version, `rar.exe`, will remove this problem.

Comment: you mean like this?  for /f "delims==" %%D in ('DIR D:\scripts /A /B /S') do( "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\RAR.EXE" a -agyyyy-MM-dd -r "c:\backup\scripts.rar" "%%D" )